# VBA copy selected record to all records on continuous form

Tags: loops, ms-access, vba, do-while

My table and form have 4 fields.
conCity, conTime, conRep, conTerrioryNumber

I need to copy the values from the Selected Record to all the records on my continuous form where conCity is the same.

This seems to copy the values to all records. How can I limit the update to only records where conCity is equal to the selected record

```
With Me.RecordsetClone
.MoveFirst
Do While .EOF = False
.Edit
   .Fields("conCity").Value = Me.conCity.Value
   .Fields("conTime").Value = Me.conTime.Value
   .Fields("conRep").Value = Me.conRep.Value
   .Fields("conTerrioryNumber").Value = Me.conTerrioryNumber.Value

.Update
.MoveNext
Loop
End With
```

Comment: I see. But what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use an `If` statement:

```
With Me.RecordsetClone
.MoveFirst
Do While .EOF = False
If .Fields("conCity").Value = Me.conCity.Value Then
.Edit
   .Fields("conCity").Value = Me.conCity.Value
   .Fields("conTime").Value = Me.conTime.Value
   .Fields("conRep").Value = Me.conRep.Value
   .Fields("conTerrioryNumber").Value = Me.conTerrioryNumber.Value

.Update
End If
.MoveNext
Loop
End With
```